# How to add tick and label above slider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i try using Slider().. divisions look good (value >= 50 ? 10 : 20)

But, How to add tick and label above slider ?

Expect :

tick will be change color following position of slider

[image: Slider]

Actual:

```
Slider(
 min: 0,
 max: 100,
 value: value,
 onChanged: (val) {
   setState(() {
     value = val;
   });
  },
 divisions: value >= 50 ? 10 : 20,
 label: value.toString(),
),
```

my problem is :

1. position of label and tick (if using column)
2. Change tick color if position of slider is same

my code using Column(

```
Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child:
          Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: List.generate(6, (index) => Text('$index')),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: List.generate(
                  16,
                  (index) => SizedBox(
                    height: 8,
                    child: VerticalDivider(
                      width: 8,
                      color: HelperColors.orange,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Slider(
          value: widget.value,
          min: widget.minValue,
          max: widget.maxValue,
          divisions: widget.divisions,
          onChanged: widget.onChanged,
          label: widget.value.toString(),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

could you help me to fix some problem on this design?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Ticks and Tick Value Layout

Instead of wrapping rows of ticks and tick values in a column, it may be better to combine both tick and tick value as a single column. Then, wrap this column with `Expanded` widget and put it in `List.generate` of a row. This guarantees  the tick always aligns with the tick value and each column has equal spacing.

#### Ticks and Slider Alignment

The slider comes with offset by default to make room for thumb and overlay. Even though you precisely calculate the spacing between ticks on your screen, the spacing will still stretch when it is tested on different screen size.

Please check this link if you are interested in learning more about Slider offset/ margin.
[Slider offset issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37057)

Here what you need to do to achieve perfect alignment

1. Remove the offset by creating custom `trackShape` of slider.
2. Measure the offset of one tick spacing and divide it by 2.
   The formula is `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / numOfTick / 2`
3. Wrap zero-offset slider with `Padding` widget and use the calculated offset as horizontal padding value. `padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: offset),`

   ```
   offset
     V
   |---|
   .----------/   /------------.
   |   0   |           |  100  |    
   |       |Ticks area |       |
   |   |   |           |   |   ||
   .----------/   /------------.|
   |                           ||
   |       Slider area         ||Screen edge
   |                           ||
   '----------/  /-------------'|
   ```
4. Now ticks and slider will always be perfectly aligned, edge-to-edge, regardless screen size.

Here's the example. You may still want to improve the UI as per your requirements.

What's supported

1. Adjustable major and minor ticks
2. Tick highlighting when value matches
3. Value precision control

```dart
double value = 50;
double actualValue = 50;
double minValue = 0;
double maxValue = 100;
List<double> steps = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,60,70,80,90,100];

// ...

CustomSlider(
            minValue: minValue,
            maxValue: maxValue,
            value: value,
            majorTick: 6,
            minorTick: 2,
            labelValuePrecision: 0,
            tickValuePrecision: 0,
            onChanged: (val) => setState(() {
              value = val;
              actualValue =
                  steps[(val / maxValue * (steps.length - 1)).ceil().toInt()];
              print('Slider value (linear): $value');
              print('Actual value (non-linear): $actualValue');
            }),
            activeColor: Colors.orange,
            inactiveColor: Colors.orange.shade50,
            linearStep: false,
            steps: steps,
          ),
```

Custom slider widget

```dart
class CustomSlider extends StatelessWidget {
  final double value;
  final double minValue;
  final double maxValue;
  final int majorTick;
  final int minorTick;
  final Function(double)? onChanged;
  final Color? activeColor;
  final Color? inactiveColor;
  final int labelValuePrecision;
  final int tickValuePrecision;
  final bool linearStep;
  final List<double>? steps;

  CustomSlider({
    required this.value,
    required this.minValue,
    required this.maxValue,
    required this.majorTick,
    required this.minorTick,
    required this.onChanged,
    this.activeColor,
    this.inactiveColor,
    this.labelValuePrecision = 2,
    this.tickValuePrecision = 1,
    this.linearStep = true,
    this.steps,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final allocatedHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final allocatedWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final divisions = (majorTick - 1) * minorTick + majorTick;
    final double valueHeight =
        allocatedHeight * 0.05 < 41 ? 41 : allocatedHeight * 0.05;
    final double tickHeight =
        allocatedHeight * 0.025 < 20 ? 20 : allocatedHeight * 0.025;
    final labelOffset = allocatedWidth / divisions / 2;

    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: List.generate(
            divisions,
            (index) => Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    height: valueHeight,
                    child: index % (minorTick + 1) == 0
                        ? Text(
                            linearStep
                                ? '${(index / (divisions - 1) * maxValue).toStringAsFixed(tickValuePrecision)}'
                                : '${(steps?[index])?.toStringAsFixed(tickValuePrecision)}',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          )
                        : null,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    height: tickHeight,
                    child: VerticalDivider(
                      indent: index % (minorTick + 1) == 0 ? 2 : 6,
                      thickness: 1.2,
                      color: (index / (divisions - 1)) * maxValue == value
                          ? activeColor ?? Colors.orange
                          : Colors.grey.shade300,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: labelOffset),
          child: SliderTheme(
            data: SliderThemeData(
              trackHeight:
                  allocatedHeight * 0.011 < 9 ? 9 : allocatedHeight * 0.011,
              activeTickMarkColor: activeColor ?? Colors.orange,
              inactiveTickMarkColor: inactiveColor ?? Colors.orange.shade50,
              activeTrackColor: activeColor ?? Colors.orange,
              inactiveTrackColor: inactiveColor ?? Colors.orange.shade50,
              thumbColor: activeColor ?? Colors.orange,
              overlayColor: activeColor == null
                  ? Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.1)
                  : activeColor!.withOpacity(0.1),
              thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 12.0),
              trackShape: CustomTrackShape(),
              showValueIndicator: ShowValueIndicator.never,
              valueIndicatorTextStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 12,
              ),
            ),
            child: Slider(
              value: value,
              min: minValue,
              max: maxValue,
              divisions: divisions - 1,
              onChanged: onChanged,
              label: value.toStringAsFixed(labelValuePrecision),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CustomTrackShape extends RoundedRectSliderTrackShape {
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
  }) {
    final double trackHeight = sliderTheme.trackHeight!;
    final double trackLeft = offset.dx;
    final double trackTop =
        offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - trackHeight) / 2;
    final double trackWidth = parentBox.size.width;
    return Rect.fromLTWH(trackLeft, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);
  }
}
```

Test

[image: Portrait]
[image: Landscape]

#### Edit (slider with non-linear steps)

Because Flutter slider has linear value-position mapping, it may not be a good idea to alter the slider value based on non-linear values. However, it is still possible to achieve that by creating additional value range for actual value then map them together.

Here are the steps

1. Create a list which contains non-linear values (the one you created)
2. Make sure the length of the list matches the total number of tick. Otherwise, the mapping will be incorrect.
   `listLength = (majorTick - 1) * minorTick + majorTick`

The above code has been edited to address this issue.

Test

[image: Nonlinear]

Mapped values

```
                           Start                            End
Slider value (linear)      0.00 6.67 13.33 ... 86.67 93.33 100.0
Actual value (non-linear)  0.00 5.00 10.00 ... 80.00 90.00 100.0
```

Comment: but, i just want to know.. how to send selected index value of thick to onChanged ?..  i've value `values = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];` .... so, i've set value to top label.. but, i see (index) inside `List.generate` and outside Slider().. so i can't pass selectedIndex to onChanged

Comment: The tick area is just a UI decoration. Even though you manage to extract the index and pass it to the parent widget, you will end up changing the behaviour of slider. The main reason is because slider value and position are linearly mapped. Meanwhile, the element steps in the list are not linear. So, one of the ways to achieve this is to create 2 value ranges, one for slider and the one for the actual value. Both have to have the same length for correct mapping. But be very careful because it is prone to unwanted bugs if it is not mapped correctly. More details in the answer section.