# How custom slider using list?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i've list from BE, but, may be will change value inside list.. because this value from BE

```
var values = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]; <<== 0-15
```

so, i want set value to Slider using list

Expect:

[image: Slider]

1. Slider have tick from list length (will be have tick 16 from List, may be will change from BE)
2. Every tick will return value from list if similar index
3. if i move slider to index 1 => 5,, index 2 => 10, index 3 => 15 etc. like value inside List

Actual:

1. Devision of Slider() is ==>> Max / devision
2. so, i can't using Division of Slider. because, if i give division 16 will be ==> 100 / 16 and return index 1 => 6.25,, index 2 => 12.5,, index 3 => 18.75 etc..

my code:

```
double value = 0;

    Slider(
      value: value,
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() {
           value = val;
           print(value);
           });
          },
      divisions: values.length,
      min: values.first.toDouble(),
      max: values.last.toDouble(),
    ),
```

but, this Slider() can't be use like that.. i must custom Slider() to create tick and set value to every tick.. so, every tick will have value like list from BE

Comment: for custom track you need to extend `SliderTrackShape` and pass its instance to `SliderThemeData.trackShape` property

Comment: SliderTrackShape to handle discrete value ?... because, i want handle discrete value using value of list @pskink

Comment: ok, post a `Slider` image with what ticks you expect to be drawn

Comment: i've create post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69342065/how-to-add-tick-and-label-above-slider] .. i see UI is fine.. but, my leader say.. i must custom Slider to fix this.. i must create tick similar value inside list from BE... because, value from list may be will change future from BE... so, this slider must be flexible using value from List to increase or decrease tick and every tick will return value like list index value .. i've see code of Slider() four days.. but, i don't understand how to custom this code to fix this case @pskink